# How to validate UITableviewCell label and Imageview data with UI Test Cases

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UITableView with some data coming from a web service. It has multiple UILabels and UIImageView in every cell. How can I get labels and UIImageView from a cell and validate if they have valid data? I want to test it for first cell only

I am able to get the first cell instance as following but unable to get its child elements.

My Code to get first cell:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
        let myTable = app.tables.matching(identifier: "property_list_tableview")
        let cell = myTable.cells.element(matching: .cell, identifier: "cell_0")
```

Now I want to extract labels and imageview from the cell. I have already added accessibility identifiers for labels and imageviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following to compare text for label value

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let myTable = app.tables["property_list_tableview"]
XCTAssertEqual(myTable.cells["cell_0"].staticTexts["field_name"].label, "Text to compare")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to add accessibility labels as UI identifiers, and then you can easily select it and get its value.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
  ...
  let = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell")! as! CustomCell

  cell.yourUIImage.image?.accessibilityLabel = "image " + String(indexPath.row)

}
```

then in UITests.swift

```
func testAreImagesLoaded() {
    let image = "image "

    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().images[image + String(0)].exists)
    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().images[image + String(1)].exists)
    XCTAssert(XCUIApplication().images[image + String(2)].exists)
}
```

you can access value for string example

```
let labelElement = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["myLabel"]
...
XCTAssertEqual(labelElement.value as! String, "your text")
```

but don't forget to add accessibility label for UILabel

see this link for more info https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/automated-ui-testing-in-swift-ios-46e1c9993316

Comment: Hi I have tried it like this: let labelElement = cell.staticTexts["property_name_0"]
        XCTAssertEqual(labelElement.value as! String, "STF Vandrarhem Stigbergsliden")
        but it is still failing

Comment: When I print the value for labelElement.value, it is empty

Comment: try to read value from accessibility inspector, check if is it set right.
In Xcode, select Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector.